# How can i pass query params as arguments in angularjs http services

Tags: angularjs

How can i pass query params as arguments in angularjs http services.
My controller code is:

```
   FetchHeadCategoryService.get({
     'officeJndi': officeJndi
      }, function (response) {
     $scope.headCategories = response;
    });
```

Service.js

```
   module.factory('FetchHeadCategoryService', [
        '$resource',
        'SYSTEM',
        function($resource, SYSTEM) {
            return $resource(SYSTEM.ENV.API_END_POINT
                    + 'v1/utility/headCategories/:officeJndi ', {
                officeJndi : '@officeJndi'
            }, {
                get : {
                    method : 'GET',
                    isArray : true
                }
            });
        } ]);
```

HeadCategory.java

```
public Response fetchDocMgmtHeadCategory(@PathParam(value = "officeJndi") final String officeJndi, @QueryParam(value = "limitFrom") final int limitFrom,@QueryParam(value = "noOfRows") final int noOfRows){
..
..
..
}
```

I can obtain the result without passing the query params by managing them in the code.
But I want to send the value of query params "limitFrom" and "NoOfRows" to the service ,so that i acn fetch the data accordingly.Can somebody HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `params` option to send additional data

```
get : {
    method : 'GET',
    isArray : true,
    params: /* your data {} */
}
```